# How to make a shortcut to the Phone app (so it can then be given its own icon on the home screen)

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

On iOS 17.3, is there a way to make a shortcut to the Phone app, so that it can then be given its own icon on the home screen?

All I can find when creating a shortcut using Shortcuts is Add Action | All Actions, and then a choice of specific Phone-related actions, such as Call and Phone Number. What I would like is to have a shortcut to the front door of the Phone app, so that when clicked on it gives exactly the same as I get when clicking on the Phone icon.

Comment: OK, I have to ask, why can't you just tap on the phone.app icon as it can be placed anywhere you like just like any other app?

Comment: If you are asking why I want to change the Apple-supplied icon, it's because in general I prefer words to icons (and books to comics) and I would like to have a word saying "Phone" that I can press on.